# Advanced DateDiff using MSExcel

Tags: excel, datediff

I have an Excel spreadsheet listing job shifts... four columns that are important for our purposes:

- Start Date
- Start Time
- End Date
- End Time

Given this data, I need to abstract the number of hours for each shift that fall between **7am** and **7pm**.

**A few things to keep in mind...**

There is no theoretical limit to the length of a shift.  It could run anywhere from 1 hour to 3 days.

I'm open to solutions in C#, VB, PHP, or even an advanced Excel function... anything to get to the solution.

Comment: how are the dates & times stored in the spreadsheet? Are you using an actual excel date or time field format? If so then you should be able to just say end-start and that would get you how long the shift is. from that you can check to see if < 12 hours and start > 7am and end < 7pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA <s>, not taking much account of minutes. I do not know if you need minutes.</s>

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ShiftRange As Range
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim HourCount As Long
Dim MinCount As Long

Set ShiftRange = Sheet1.UsedRange

For i = 2 To ShiftRange.Rows.Count
    HourCount = 0
    dteStart = CDate(Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i, 2))
    dteEnd = CDate(Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i, 4))

    Do While dteStart <= dteEnd
        If Hour(dteStart) >= 7 And Format(dteStart, "hh:mm") <= #7:00:00 PM# Then
            HourCount = HourCount + 1
        End If

        dteStart = DateAdd("h", 1, dteStart)
    Loop

    MinCount = HourCount * 60

    ''Minutes
    If CDate(Cells(i, 2)) >= #7:00:00 AM# And CDate(Cells(i, 2)) <= #7:00:00 PM# Then
         MinCount = MinCount - Minute(CDate(Cells(i, 2)))
    End If

    If CDate(Cells(i, 4)) >= #7:00:00 AM# And CDate(Cells(i, 4)) <= #7:00:00 PM# Then
        MinCount = MinCount + Minute(CDate(Cells(i, 4)))
    End If

    Cells(i, 6) = MinCount 
Next
```

This assumes that A, B, C and D are the columns that contain dates and times and that colum F is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Remou
Very nice and workable.

I made a change to allow for parts of hours

```
Sub DayHours()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ShiftRange As Range
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim MinCount As Double

Set ShiftRange = Sheet1.UsedRange

For i = 3 To ShiftRange.Rows.Count
MinCount = 0
dteStart = CDate(Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i, 4))
dteEnd = CDate(Cells(i, 5) + Cells(i, 6))

Do While dteStart <= dteEnd
    If Format(dteStart, "hh:mm") >= #7:00:00 AM# And Format(dteStart, "hh:mm") < #7:00:00 PM# Then
        MinCount = MinCount + 1
    End If

    dteStart = DateAdd("n", 1, dteStart)
Loop
Cells(i, 10) = MinCount / 60
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a slightly different approach to minutes. I will add it above.